# What happens to the energy?

Tags: energy, acoustics, vacuum, vibrations

if we make a bell ring in a  vacuum room for 5 mins. And then open the door, will be able to hear the sound?  If no sounds vibrations are emitted to the environment what happens to the energy that would normally be carried away by the sound?

Comment: If you throw a rock into a dry lake and then fill the lake up with water do you see the ripples made by the rock?  No and the answer is no for your question too. The vibrations from the bell aren't transfered to the surrounding air because in a vacuum there is no surrounding air.  They are lost forever.  Adding air to the room after the fact doesn't change anything.

Comment: but what happens to the sound energy...in what form it converts?

Comment: The vibrating bell losses energy to internal heating of the metal the bell is made out of.  It will get warmer and warmer until it reaches a temperature where energy lost to the thermal radiation (mostly infrared) balances out the energy gained absorbing the vibrations from the ringer.

Comment: I have edited your question to include your question about what happens to the energy.  Now it's a much more interesting question.  Please take a look and fix my edit if you think it needs adjustment.

Answer (score 3):

If the bell is still vibrating when you let air inside it, then the answer is yes. If the bell was damped just before the door is opened, then the answer is no.

Sound is transmitted through compression / decompression waves (pressure waves) in a medium (e.g. air, water, wall). This necessitates contact of the vibrating source of sound with such a medium.

In vacuum, there is no such medium, and the sound waves can not spread in the room.

When a bell "rings" in vacuum, it continues to vibrate longer than it would in air, since it does not collide with the air molecules and transfers its momentum to them. It would not vibrate indefinitely because it's energy would be transferred to heat eventually.